# Facebook connect and phonegap

Tags: android, ios, facebook, cordova, facebook-graph-api

i'm making a phonegap web application and i need to put Facebook's login in it.

i was not able to install phonegap's Facebook login  but i find this very interesting library http://coenraets.org/blog/2014/04/facebook-phonegap-cordova-without-plugin/ i installed and it works fine on my iphone with phonegap desktop app (by using phonegap localhost as Valid OAuth redirect URIs in Facebook for example: http://localhost:3000/pathto/index.html) but when i open my local project from file://pathto/index.html it doesn't works, the redirect uri is invalid.

1- is there a way to allow all redirect uri?
2- when i build the app with build.phonegap and make the iphone/android app it will work with this redirect uri? if not? what is the redirect uri that i should put?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use this redirect uri:

```
https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html
```

Also make sure you have added the inappbrowser core plugin:

```
cordova plugins add org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser
```